# Copying file in emacs using existing file name as a "base"

Tags: emacs, copy, dired

When in a Dired buffer, is it possible to copy an existing file to a new file using the existing files name as a "base" and then edit it to create a new file name?  I know you cannot copy a file to a new file with the exact same name.  What I have been doing is copying the old file name to a register, using `Shift-C` on the old file name, and then pasting and editing the new file name. I'm looking for a way to do this that allows me to skip the step of copying the old file name to a register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `C` in Dired to copy the file of the current line to another file. At the prompt, use `M-n` to retrieve the existing file's name as the default, and edit it.

*Throughout Emacs*, `M-n` when you see a prompt retrieves the default value for your input.  For file-name input in Dired, `M-n` typically retrieves the name of the file on the current line.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you so much.  I've been using emacs for 30 years and am still learning some of its tricks.

Comment: I know what you mean - always stuff like this to discover.

Comment: @GregW. since the answer seems to have answered your question you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it (you can also [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it if you want but you need 15 reputation points for that.).

Comment: Very useful thank you but  It's not in the emacs key index so how do you know that?

Comment: @RaoulHATTERER: Sure it is -- it's listed as this entry: [M-n (minibuffer history)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-History.html). (And it's mentioned in many other places in the Emacs manual - just search there for `M-n`.)

Comment: @Drew: I knew `M-n` and `M-p` to navigate the minibuffer history but I was missing the "This includes completion candidates (such as file names, buffer names, command names, etc.) and any other kind of minibuffer input." part. So thank you again.

Comment: @RaoulHATTERER: Yes, well, it *shouldn't* automatically include all completion candidates. That was an unfortunate "enhancement" made to Emacs: stuffing all candidates in the completion domain into the list of `DEFAULTS` that `M-n` inserts. `DEFAULTS` should be limited to the list of entries defined by the programmer writing the call to `completing-read` etc. Just one opinion, and not heeded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what sort of setup this works with, but It's not mine.

For instance, if I'm trying to copy `prepare-commit-msg.sample` to `prepare-commit-msg`, emacs will autocomplete the partial filename when I hit enter from the following:
[image]
I then receive this message:
[image]

The solution (for me, I'm not sure what all I've added to make it so) is, instead of "Enter", hitting `C-M-j` resulting in a new file that is the exact beginning of an already existing file:
[image]